# at login via console or ssh after entering password it says "the system is going down"

Tags: login

raspberry pi, raspian, after entering the user name at the console, instead of asking for the password it says "The system is going down..." and then it prompts for the user name again. If I ssh and enter the password is says "The system is going down..." and then closes the connection.

Answer (score 3):

/etc/nologin exists. It is created during shutdown and removed during boot, but something went wrong. If you set a root password, root can login while this file is present to cancel the shutdown or to remove the file. If you don't have a root password set, powerfailing may put the system in a reasonable state. If that does  not work you will have to either boot into single user recovery mode or mount your root file system from another machine and fix it that way.